# Editing/changing runlevels?

Tags: fedora, runlevel

I learned linux on redhat/fedora systems, and I really like there runlevels.
The runlevels in ubuntu (inherited from debian i'm sure) are weird, there is no way to get a no GUI environment unless your turn off all the services manually (your display manager, desktop, login manager, etc.), which is frustrating.

Is there any way to change my runlevels, so that they are the same as fedora's?
And if I do that, will it negatively impact my system? (are other programs dependent on the default runlevels?)

Thank you, Steven.

Comment: Not very easily, to a large extent runlevels are less meaningful with upstart. You would have to edit the upstart config files to your liking and define the runlevels you want. This would be a manual process. See http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/